# LibreOffice Calc: SUMIFS based on each row condition

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Assume I have the following data:

[image]

I want to do a calculation based on each currency and amount. Something like:

[image]

So money in (for USD) will be the sum of column H where the amount is positive, and the currency is USD. Money out (for USD) will be the sum of column H where the amount is negative, and the currency is USD.

How to calculate this? I'm thinking of using SUMIFS, but I always get Err:502.
My formula is :

> =SUMIFS($H$2:$H$65440, G2, "USD", H2, ">0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [Libreoffice documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_sumifs.html?DbPAR=CALC)

> Func_Range and Range1, Range2... must have the same size, otherwise the function returns err:502 - Invalid argument.

So you must use ranges in your conditions, and your formula should be

```
=SUMIFS($H$2:$H$65440, $G$2:$G$65440, "USD", $H$2:$H$65440, ">0")
```